# The meaning of the comma inside X[:,0]

Tags: python, indexing

If `X` is an array, what is the meaning of `X[:,0]`? In fact, it is not the first time I see such thing, and it's confusing me, but I can't see what is its meaning? Could anyone be able to show me an example? A full clear answer would be appreciated on this question of comma.

Please see the file https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/blob/master/ann_class/forwardprop.py

Comment: Is this a pandas `Dataframe`? Please give more examples of the code. Currently `X` is a little cryptic.

Comment: No, it is from the file https://github.com/lazyprogrammer/machine_learning_examples/blob/master/ann_class/forwardprop.py

Comment: Then it's a numpy array, this selects the first column of data.

Comment: The comma is basically the delimiter between dimensions, where ```:``` is something like a wildcard. But the numpy-docs will be much better at explaining this!

Answer (score 20):

The comma inside the bricks seperates the rows from the columns you want to slide from your array.

```
x[row,column]
```

You can place ":" before or after the row and column values. Before the value it means "unitl" and after the value it means "from".

For example you have:

```
x: array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
          [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
          [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
          [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
          [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
          [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
          [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
          [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
          [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2]])

x[:,:] would mean u want every row and every column.

x[3,3] would mean u want the 3 row and the 3 column value

x[:3,:3] would mean u want the rows and columns until 3

x[:, 3] would mean u want the 3 column and every row
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[:, 0] Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

If you see that, then the variable *is not a list*, but something else. A numpy array, perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not answering my question.

Answer (score 2):

I am creating an example matrix:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)  
F = np.random.randint(2,5, size=(3, 4), dtype = 'int32' )
F
```

[image]

Query cutting matrix rows:

```
F[0:2]
```

[image]

Query cutting matrix columns:

```
F[:,2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to be straight at point it is `X[rows, columns]` as some one mentioned but you may ask wat just colon means `:` in `"X[:,0]"` it means you say list all.

So `X[:,0]` - > would say list elements in all rows as it just colon `:` present in first column so the column of entire matrix is printed out. dimension is `[no_of_rows * 1]`

Similarly, `X[:,1]`  - > this would list the second column from all rows.

Hope this clarifies you

Answer (score 0):

**Pretty clear. Check this out!**

Load some data

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

samples = iris.data
```

Explore first 10 elements of 2D array

```
samples[:10]
array([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2],
       [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2],
       [5. , 3.6, 1.4, 0.2],
       [5.4, 3.9, 1.7, 0.4],
       [4.6, 3.4, 1.4, 0.3],
       [5. , 3.4, 1.5, 0.2],
       [4.4, 2.9, 1.4, 0.2],
       [4.9, 3.1, 1.5, 0.1]])
```

Test our annotation

```
x = samples[:,0]
x[:10]
array([5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5. , 5.4, 4.6, 5. , 4.4, 4.9])

y = samples[:,1]
y[:10]
array([3.5, 3. , 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1])
```

P.S. The length of `samples` is 150, I've cut it to 10 for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently `X` is a 2D np array , then `X[:,0]` means you want every element of `X` from it's first row (row zero) .

Elements are denoted by their respective row and column numbers,
for example :

```
a = X[1,2]
```

'a' is an element of 'X', from the second column and third row.

Basically the comma separates row and column and colon in place of row means every row.

**note;**

```
X[:3,0]
```

means : every row until third row , column zero.

```
X[3:,0]
```

means : every row from third row , column zero.